# Embedding from one $\mathscr L$-structure to another consisting of unary functions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I've been trying to solve this question with no luck.

> Let $\mathscr L$ be a language consisting of a single unary function $f$.  Let  $\mathbf A$ be an $\mathscr L$-structure with its underlying set as the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ and $f^\mathbf A$ the function $x \mapsto x +1$. Let  $\mathbf B$ be an $\mathscr L$-structure with its underlying set as the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ and $f^\mathbf B$ the function $x \mapsto 2x$.
>   Give an embedding of $\mathbf A$ into $\mathbf B$.

I know the embedding must be a one-to-one mapping $\phi: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N$ such that for $a,b \in \mathbb N$, $f^\mathbf A(a)=b$ iff $f^\mathbf B(\phi(a))=\phi(b)$, but I can't really think of such a mapping that would satisfy this. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about this? Would some kind of piecewise mapping be needed?

Comment: Write the condition differently : $f^\mathbf{B}(\phi(a)) = \phi(f^\mathbf{A}(a))$. Now this tells us that $f^\mathbf{B}(\phi(a)) = \phi(a+1)$. Do you now see how to define $\phi$ ?

Comment: Thanks for responding! So we need to find a mapping such that $2(\phi(a))=\phi(a+1)$, right? That's what I thought, but finding the actual mapping doesn't seem to be very obvious.

Comment: Do you know recursion ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition

Comment: Yeah, I do. Are you supposed to use $\phi(a)$ to define $\phi(a+1)$ in some way? (sorry, I'm feeling a little lost!)

Comment: Maybe you'll be more comfortable writing the previous relation as $u_{n+1} = 2u_n$ ?

Comment: Choose a value of your liking for $\phi(0)$. Then write $\phi(1)$, $\phi(2)$, $\phi(3)$, $\phi(4)$, $\phi(5)$ determined by the equation you wrote above. Try some specific numbers.